# How to import data form csv files into CNN?

Tags: python, csv, classification

I want to make a classification with CNN. My data set format structure is as follow:
label1:
--1.csv
--2.csv
labels2:
--1.csv
--2.csv
And a matrix is stored in each CSV file. Previously, I succeeded in making a classification by using pictures data. When inputting these Pictures into CNN, they are transformed into matrix elements. Now, the program treats the path of csv file as s string. I'm not sure what to do with this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which CNN are you trying? How have you tried to load the data from csv? Can you post the relevant part(s) of your code and the output or error message?

Answer (score 0):

Please specify what software or packages you are using for your CNN. (Tensorflow? Pytorch?) For CNNs your labels must be numeric, e.g. a numeric vector. I'm not sure if you are using python but if so, you can use pandas to open a csv and then convert it to a numpy array using:

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.read_csv('label1.csv')
x_as_array = x.values
```

For more background on CNNs you can see [this post](https://glassboxmedicine.com/2019/05/05/how-computers-see-intro-to-convolutional-neural-networks/).